# Fetch/Listen for a new message in the channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello so I'm making a bot that will fetch a message in a specific channel, copies it and then sent it to another channel. I tried using `messages.fetch()` but it doesn't work and always returns with `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`. This is what my code is currently like :

```
  if (message.content === 'Log'){
message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 10})
.then(messages => {
  message.channel.send(messages)}).catch(console.error)}
```

I hope anyone can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the bot to output the content of the last 10 messages in the channel, this should work:

```js
let msgs = [];
message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 10})
.then(messages => {
    return messages.each(msg => msgs.push(msg.content));
})
.then(messages => {
    message.channel.send(msgs.reverse().join("\n")); // outputs the messages separated by a newline
});
```

If you only want to get one message you can just do:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch("MESSAGE_ID")
.then(msg => {
    message.channel.send(msg.content);
});
```

[Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Comment: Is there any way for the bot to constantly look for a new message?

Comment: @Prism Not sure what you mean exactly, maybe [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) will be useful.